# What the use of adding the extra "async" to airflow?

Tags: gunicorn, airflow

I used to install, configure and use Airflow daily. I have a new project and it's going to be the first time I install airflow 2.0 from scratch.

Reading the documentation about the difference between the two versions I saw that in the extra packet we can install with airflow "async" is available (it's not new and it's available for the v1). I never face a tutorial or a medium article talking about using "Async worker classes for Gunicorn" like you can read in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/extra-packages-ref.html).

Do anybody can explain to me the benefit for this extra package ?

Answer (score 1):

The Gunicorn HTTP Server has [different classes of workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#sync-workers): sync, async, etc. Based on the expected load, it may be beneficial to [chose one worker class](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#choosing-a-worker-type) over the other. For example, the assumption behind choosing the sync class is that the web application (requests to which will be served by the sync workers) is resource-bound in terms of CPU and network bandwidth.

[Airflow webserver uses the sync class by default.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-class). I don't have a real-world example in favor of the async class. But I could imagine some custom plugin that extends the Airflow's webserver and has some long-lasting IO-bound logic might benefit from async workers. Although, this is just a guess...